# Typescript (at-loader) compiler errors in WebPack

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to write an Angular SPA, but I use WebPack to run it.  Currently I let VS build the Typescript into JS and WebPack uses that JS to create the build artefact.

I want to move to WebPack building the Typescript so its easier for our CI server to build the project.  For some reason VS can compile the Typescript fine but `awesome-typescript-loader` cannot.

My Typescript is written using ES6 modules i.e.

```
import * as angular from "angular";
import * as moment from "moment";
import "angular-material";

import { ExpensesService } from "../../main/components/reports/expenses/expenses.service";
import { IJourney } from "../../Interface/IJourney";
```

I get these errors from WebPack / Awesome-Typescript-Loader when I compile run it. Note that all of these are in the `node_modules` folder and not my code (that I can tell?)

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:32:11
>       TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Error'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/lib-esm/services.d.ts:9:9
>       TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'stateProvider' must be of type 'StateProvider', but here has
>   type 'StateProvider'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/lib/runtime.d.ts:20:13
>       TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type
>   'WebpackRequire'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/tsutils/src/typeguard.d.ts:140:70
>       TS2694: Namespace 'ts' has no exported member 'EnumLiteralType'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/uri-js/src/punycode.d.ts:9:17
>       TS2714: The expression of an export assignment must be an identifier or qualified name in an ambient context.

My `tsconfig.json` (which I force VS to use) is

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "lib": [ "es2015" ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "typings"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "node_modules/**/*.d.ts",
        "scripts/typings/d.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./src/app/bootstrap.ts"
    ]
}
```

I won't copy `packages.json` here for brevity, but I include all appropriate npm packages i.e. `@types/angular`, `@types/angular-material` etc.

In my WebPack.config here is the relevant setup

```
module.rules = {
    {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"],
    },
}
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
    modules: [node_modules"]
},
```

Comment: I think the cause of the error is you're compiling the definition files, try removing `"node_modules/**/*.d.ts"` and `"scripts/typings/d.ts"` in **tsconfig.json** .

Comment: @AmayaSan Thank you so much! Could you write an answer please so I can accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the error is you're compiling the definition files

To fix it

removing `"node_modules/**/*.d.ts"` and `"scripts/typings/d.ts"`

in **tsconfig.json** will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, excluding in the `tsconfig.json` didn't work as it works for not implicit compiling, but still goes to the files if explicitly required, and `exclude` anyway work just to ***reduce*** `include` set.

Adding `skipLibCheck` to `tsconfig.json` solved the problem:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "skipLibCheck": true,
    },
    // ...
}
```

***NOTE***: This was using `awesome-typescript-loader` in webpack. With `ts-loader` i didn't have problem.